# capturing data from clients as hex using twisted Python

Tags: python, sockets, twisted

I need to code server application to which more than 100 clients are connected and these clients are embedded machines which send some hex data through tcp sockets every 2 minutes. Earlier I coded same thing successfully in C# but now I want to code same thing in python using twisted. Since I am new to python I am facing certain problems. In C# I was storing data from clients directly in byte array and then processing that bytes array. Now I want to do same thing in python but I couldn't found how to do it? The following code just shows the hex->ascii->char.

```
def rawDataReceived(self, data):
            print "hello"
            print data
```

My question how do I convert this data to bytes array or directly capture data as bytes?
for example the clients want to send 'w' alphabet it will send server 77 as 1 byte. My current code shows w but how do I convert it bytes array something like bytes[] array[0] = 0x77.

Comment: You're just looking to get the numeric value of each byte? Or trying to build a hexlified string or something?

Comment: The client will send server 777777 and I want to code for server app as byte[] araray = {0x77, 0x77, 0x77}.

Comment: Well, `byte[]` is not a Python type, but `bytearray` is pretty close to what you're looking for. Also, `{}` is for (unordered) sets in Python, not (ordered) sequences. But I think my answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Remember that "hex" is just a representation of bytes.  The Python builtin string type (`str`) is a sequence of bytes.  dataReceived(/rawDataReceived) are called with a string - that is, with bytes.  You have the bytes you are looking for already - the real question is what you want to do with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an array of bytes from a `str`, use [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray):*

```
>>> data = 'hello'
>>> array = bytearray(data)
>>> array[0]
104
>>> hex(array[0])
0x68
>>> array[0] == 0x68
True
```

Alternatively, you can convert the characters to bytes one by one with [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord):

```
>>> ord(data[0])
104
```

So these are equivalent:

```
>>> list(bytearray(data)) == [ord(c) for c in data]
True
```

---

* Note that the docs are a bit confusing here. They say that a string requires an encoding, but that's really only true in Python 3.x (which is odd for docs explicitly written for version 2.7). In 2.x, `str` conforms to the buffer interface, so it doesn't need an encoding.

Comment: From the question, I'm not sure it's really clear that this is going to help out.  For example, consider the fact that in your example `data[0] == '\x68'` - so why is a bytearray (such that `array[0] == 0x68`) better than a str for whatever problem the poster has encountered?  Since he doesn't explain the problem it's hard to say.  (in other words, I wonder if the poster isn't just confused about representations and this extra information may just serve to further confuse him)

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: He says he wants the equivalent of a C# `byte[]`. That's exactly what a `bytearray` is. Also, getting the number `0x68` instead of the character `'\x68'` seems to be what he's trying to do.

Comment: yes abarnet is correct I am looking for getting 0x68,0x77.. as array elements.

Comment: It's not clear to me how that's interestingly different from '\x68\x77...'.  But, okay!  Have fun.

Comment: I completely new python so in C# I was just storing data from clients in byte[] array where array[0] = 0x77, array[1] = 0x6B and so on. I just need to do like this python also and abarnet code is doing like this.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: Numbers are different from strings, in many interesting and useful ways. You can't subtract two strings, or shift one string 8 bits left and or in another, or…

Comment: I wouldn't readily agree with "Numbers are different from strings" but I think you're entirely correct to say that the operations easily available on strings are different from those easily available on integers.  However, what's really unclear is what the poster actually wants to do!  The question gives no indication of what operations will actually be applied to the data.

Comment: Incidentally (completely irrelevant to the rest of this discussion), you can shift a string left by 8 bits - just decide what fill value you want: for example, s + '\x00' for zero-fill. :)

Comment: Note: `b'hello'[0] == 104` on Python 3 i.e., `bytes` "is" an immutable `bytearray`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yeah, I didn't mention that I thought it might be confusing to a novice who only knows 2.x, where `bytes` is just a synonym for `str`, and the `b` prefix is ignored, so `b'hello'[0] == 'b'`. But it's definitely worth mentioning in a comment. Thanks.